# ld cannot find -lz in an empty environment even with LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, gcc, conda, ld, libz

I am trying to create a `conda` package that includes `c` code that have to compile with `-lz`. However, when the package is building, `ld` cannot find `zlib` even though I provide it with any paths possible.

As I understand, `conda` creates almost empty environment, and then fills it with necessary libraries and tools. It also installs `zlib`, so that there is `zlib.h` in `$BUILD_PREFIX/include/` and `libz.so, libz.a` in `$BUILD_PREFIX/lib`.

Compilation itself looks like

```
$BUILD_PREFIX/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -fPIC -g -Wall -O2 -Wc++-compat main.o -o <name> -L. -l<name> -lm -lz -lpthread
```

`x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc` is `gcc version 7.3.0`, and it calls `ld` defined here as `$BUILD_PREFIX/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld`. Then `ld` falls with an error `cannot find -lz`.

I tried using

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="$BUILD_PREFIX/include"
export LIBRARY_PATH="$BUILD_PREFIX/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$BUILD_PREFIX/lib"
export LD_PRELOAD="$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/libz.so"
```

in any combinations, but that did not work.

Are there any other ways to show `ld` path to the library?

Comment: These are all wrong. In particular, the `LD_*` ones are looked at during load time, not at link time. Pass the path via the `-L` option on the gcc command line (currently you have `-L.`, which tells gcc to tell the linker to look for libraries in the current working directory — in addition to normal system paths).

Comment: Please show the output of `cd $BUILD_PREFIX/lib && ls -l libz*`.

Comment: @zwol `libz.a` `libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.11` `libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11` `libz.so.1.2.11`. But the comment of @VladislavIvanishin helped